# Scrolling down in Chrome dev tools when paused in debugger

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to scroll down on the page while Chrome is paused in debugger mode without unpausing?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the inability to pause is an intentional feature. [*"We intentionally block all input events in the inspected page while it is paused to avoid triggering JS event handlers(including onscroll)"*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87607). At least there are workarounds.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Glad there is a way to override as well.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If your tools are docked, you can undock it to see a bit more.

Another method:

1. Go to the Elements tab.
2. Right-click on any **visible** element (i.e. not hidden, `display:none`, etc.).
3. Choose the "Scroll Into View" context menu entry.
4. Chrome will scroll the page if necessary to get the element in the visible portion of the window.

Comment: If the element is hard to find (too much nested divs, etc) and you have your element in a `var` at your stopped JS, you can hover the variable and in the yellow tooltip (or even print the element at console), right-click the element and 'Reveal in Elements panel', and then do the steps above.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Or you just use `inspect(elemnt)`, e.g. `inspect($$('selector')[0])`. (`$$` is short for `document.querySelectorAll`).

Answer (score 37):

Taken from [here](http://www.lukerodgers.ca/2012/10/scrolling-while-paused-in-chrome-debugger/).

An easy workaround for the scrolling lock-up is to just jump to the console, and:

`window.scrollTo(0, 800)`. (Replace 800 as needed)

Comment: I like scrollTo because sometimes you might not know what dom element represents what page component. So the above solution might not be efficient all the time.

Answer (score 2):

To enable scroll, enter, in console:
document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'

Comment: Works to restore scrolling on instagram after deleting the login/auth overlay divs