# Is there a way to allow scrolling while debugging in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, scroll, breakpoints

If I hit a breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools, is there a way to enable scrolling around the webpage while javascript is paused?  A lot of times when things are being injected onto the page I want to be able to see them get injected rather than have to endlessly switch to the Elements tab to look, only to be taken back to the Sources tab when I step over.

Comment: i have no idea, but you could probably put a negative top margin on the body from the console to "scroll down".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling down in Chrome dev tools when paused in debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328240/scrolling-down-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-paused-in-debugger)